# Why does align items reduce the size of my elements

Tags: html, css

I thought align-items center was used to center items along the vertical axis. But why does it just squish my form element?

css code

```
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
    font-family:sans-serif;
    background:#f6f5f7;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    height:100vh;
    margin:-20px 0 50px;

    
}

h1{
    margin:0;
    font-weight:bold;
}

p{
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:100;
    line-height:20px;
    letter-spacing:0.5px;
    margin:20px 0 30px;
    
}

span{
    font-size:12px;
}

a{
    color:#333;
    font-size:14px;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin:15px 0;
}

.container{
    background:#fff;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:768px;
    max-width:100%;
    min-height:480px;


}

.form-container form{
    background:#fff;
    flex-direction:column;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    padding:0 50px;
    height:100%;
    
    
    
  }
  form{
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    
  }
```

**If you remove the align items center you will get a long form which is not what i am looking for by long i mean the widht is longer than i need it to be. Does this have to deal with how the align properties was created or something else?**

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    

    <h2>Weekly Coding Challenge #1: Sign in/up Form</h2>
    <div class="container" id="container">
      <div class="form-container sign-up-container">
        <form action="#">
          <h1>Create Account</h1>
          <div class="social-container">
            <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
          </div>
          <span>or use your email for registration</span>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
          <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
          <button>Sign Up</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="form-container sign-in-container">
        <form action="#">
          <h1>Sign in</h1>
          <div class="social-container">
            <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
          </div>
          <span>or use your account</span>
          <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
          <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
          <button>Sign In</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="overlay-container">
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="overlay-panel overlay-left">
            <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
            <p>To keep connected with us please login with your personal info</p>
            <button class="ghost" id="signIn">Sign In</button>
          </div>
          <div class="overlay-panel overlay-right">
            <h1>Hello, Friend!</h1>
            <p>Enter your personal details and start journey with us</p>
            <button class="ghost" id="signUp">Sign Up</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <footer>
      <p>
        Created with <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> by
        <a target="_blank" href="https://florin-pop.com">Florin Pop</a>
        - Read how I created this and how you can join the challenge
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.florin-pop.com/blog/2019/03/double-slider-sign-in-up-form/">here</a>.
      </p>
    </footer>


  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to remove align-items center because i did not see its use but without it my form will be long and i was expecting it will have no effect if i removed it.

This html document is a form login website for a company and could it be that it is a regular thing for a form to be reduced by align-items center.

Can someone please exlain that will help.

Comment: Could you:make your code into a runnable snippet, I am stuck on a touch device so cannot do this for you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

The `align items: center` property aligns the items such that they align perfectly to the center of the cross axis in turn squishing all the elements inside it to their default/set width.

Instead of that you could set a `width` or a `max-width` property for the width of your form and a `margin: auto` to align it at the center of the cross-axis.

The `margin: auto` aligns it to the center because it tries to auto adjust all the 4 margins to an equal length which in turn centers it.

```
form {
   width: 70%;
   margin: auto;
}
```